# Is it possible to use InfluxDB for keeping track of customer usages (servers, desktops,etc...)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, influxdb, apache-cloudstack

I've recently started using InfluxDB for monitoring my NodeJS application in combination with Numbat. I think it's really neat and easy to setup. But I was wondering if I could use it to keep track of customer resource usages by sending metrics of their usages to InfluxDB. I would need to keep track of these customers on a per minute and month basis. The metrics come from MongoDB and CloudStack and would be retrieved on a regular interval( less than 1min).

example of an event for some metrics concerning cpu,gp:

```
usage,disk_space=100,servers_on_count=4 customer=microsoft
usage,disk_space=90,server_on_count=5 customer=apple
```

Is this something that would be feasible or would you suggest another approach?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely feasible, but I would make a few modifications, assuming that you care about the numeric properties of `disk_space` and `servers_on_count` and that you'd like to index on `customer`.

In particular I would suggests making `disk_space` and `servers_on_count` fields and `customers` a tag. So your data would look like the following:

```
usage,customer=microsoft disk_space=100,servers_on_count=4
usage,customer=apple disk_space=90,servers_on_count=5
```